# tiny system freezes on 18.04 / 2009 Macbook

Tags: xubuntu, macbook

I have a 2009 unibody macbook running xubuntu 18.04. Every now and again the mouse will freeze for about half a second. I think everything is freezing, but I don't know. It's nothing more than an irritation right now, but it's ruining the experience.

What should I be looking for and how?

CPU~Dual core Intel Core2 Duo P7550 (-MCP-) speed/max~1419/2261 MHz Kernel~5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 Up~57 min Mem~2582.1/5701.0MB HDD~240.1GB(9.9% used)

edit: This only seems to happen with USB mouse on EITHER USB port - not bluetooth mouse.

edit to add details from syslog:

```
Jan 19 12:25:28 david-FrankenBook rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="725" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  344.615346] usb usb4-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  344.615357] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:093A:2510.000B
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  344.985672] usb 4-2: new low-speed USB device number 13 using ohci-pci
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.220299] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.220303] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.220306] usb 4-2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.220308] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: PixArt
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.231056] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:093A:2510.000C$
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  345.231426] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.000C: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-00$
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2"
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:093A:2510.000C
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Jan 19 12:25:31 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2
Jan 19 12:25:54 david-FrankenBook rtkit-daemon[1242]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 19 12:25:54 david-FrankenBook rtkit-daemon[1242]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 19 12:25:55 david-FrankenBook anacron[691]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jan 19 12:26:11 david-FrankenBook rtkit-daemon[1242]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 19 12:27:37 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  471.301724] perf: interrupt took too long (4030 > 3970), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49500
Jan 19 12:26:14 david-FrankenBook rtkit-daemon[1242]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  474.396043] usb usb4-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  474.396061] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 13
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:093A:2510.000C
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook upowerd[1134]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb4/4-2
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  474.769870] usb 4-2: new low-speed USB device number 14 using ohci-pci
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  475.010950] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  475.010957] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  475.010962] usb 4-2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Jan 19 12:27:41 david-FrankenBook kernel: [  475.010967] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: PixArt
```

There is no USB hub. It's a bog standard plastic macbook and I'm using the standard USB ports built into the side.

Comment: Sounds like usb autosuspend kicks in. If you have a power saving tool installed, like TLP or laptop-mode-tools, tweak their settings to stop autosuspending that particular USB port (or all), or remove it.

Comment: I've disabled autosuspend, but not difference. It's something else

Comment: You mean for the USB devices, not just the autosuspend from system settings right (they are not related)?

Comment: Yeah. Disabled autosuspend for the individual device id based on instructions found elsewhere. I've edited the original post to add details from syslog.